# Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.)

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, twilio-api

while I use Twilio account to send SMS it shows an SSL error in python

Comment: requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twilio.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2010-04-01/Accounts/AC8c326b4a2a9f4edfecd7a2589f29aa90/Messages.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You may want to carefully read the error message and eventually do some research, then come back with what you found... If necessary, that is.